# Publishing a pandas pivot table via html

Tags: python, html, python-2.7, pandas, pivot-table

Has anyone any experience of publishing a pandas pivot table to a html page?
Its simple to publish a list as a table but i dont know the syntax for a pandas pivot.
On the bus now so ill post some code when i get in

Thanks

Comment: Are you using the Ipython notebook by chance? Then you can publish it as html from there.

Comment: Hi firelynx -no i lm using it for a script at work that runs off a regular laptop. Basically it pulls info from a db, pivots it, does some calcs then i publish that on a html page so it needs to work outaide ipython

Comment: Then the Ipython notebook (It's not a laptop, it's a web-server) may be very interesting to you. It's what most people who use pandas use to display reports. http://ipython.org/notebook.html You can also use the Ipython notebooks' extensions in a programmatic way, with the interactive part.

Answer (score 6):

A pivot table is nothing else than a DataFrame, so it has the `to_html()` method described in the docs [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_html.html)

It will output html code for the table, for example, with this very simple dataframe:

```
In [1]: df
Out[1]:
    A   B
0   0   1
1   2   3

In [2]: print df.to_html()
Out[2]:

<table border="1" class="dataframe">
  <thead>
    <tr style="text-align: right;">
      <th></th>
      <th>A</th>
      <th>B</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>0</th>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>1</th>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thats a very sexy answer! Ill need to try it out but i have a baby due in the next 48hrs so my priorities have changed slightly! Ill take a look as soon as i can and thank u!

Comment: Cool. Good luck with the baby!

Comment: That save my day!! Thanks Julien