# df.style does not correctly render pivot table generated from a pandas dataframe in Django

Tags: python, django, pandas, dataframe, pandas-styles

I am trying to render a pandas DataFrame to a Django template with some style options. My problem may be related to this issue: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/13140.

I have gone through these answers in stack overflow regarding this question:

1. [Apply CSS class to Pandas DataFrame using to_html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50807744/apply-css-class-to-pandas-dataframe-using-to-html)
2. [Publishing a pandas pivot table via html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31424202/publishing-a-pandas-pivot-table-via-html)
3. [How do I preserve hierarchical tables with pandas pivot_table and dataframe styles?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37166730/how-do-i-preserve-hierarchical-tables-with-pandas-pivot-table-and-dataframe-styl)

Here is my models.py

```
class Fruit(models.Model):
    fruit_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    car_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    week = models.DecimalField(max_digits=3, decimal_places=1, blank=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=3, decimal_places=1, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s & %s' % (self.fruit_name, self.car_name)
```

And views.py

```
def get_fruit(request, *args, **kwargs):
    df = pd.DataFrame(list(Fruit.objects.all().values('fruit_name', 'car_name', 'week', 'price')))
    df2 = df
    cols = ['week', 'price']
    df2[cols] = df2[cols].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')
    df3 = pd.pivot_table(df2, index='car_name', columns=['fruit_name', 'week'], values='price', fill_value='')
    df3_index = df3.index
    html = df2.style.applymap(color_red, subset=['price']).render()

    df3_html = df3.style \
        .applymap(color_red, subset=df3_index) \
        .render()

    context = {'html': html,
               'df3_html': df3_html
               }
    return render(request, 'get_fruit.html', context)

def color_red(s):
    color = 'red' if (-5.0 <= s >= 5.0) else 'black'
    return 'color: %s' % color
```

get_fruit.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}

    <h1> Table</h1>
  {{ html | safe}}
<br>
    <h1>Pivot table</h1>
  {{ df3_html | safe }}

{% endblock %}
```

The template renders as:[image: get_fruit webpage]

As you can see from the above picture, df.style is working for my table (where values > 5 are red) but not for the pivot table. I am not sure if it's  a bug or is it something in my code.

I am using Django: 2.0.6; Jinja2: 2.10; pandas: 0.23.1 and Python: 3.6.

I appreciate any help.

Comment: In your `subset`, you specify *indices* instead of columns.

Comment: If I do columns it throws the following error: ("'<=' not supported between instances of 'float' and 'str'", 'occurred at index (Apple, 6.0)')

Comment: yes, you need to exclude the `fruit_name`s of course.

Comment: I am not sure how. if i do: exclude_1 = df3.columns.droplevel(1)
    df3_columns = df3.columns(exclude=exclude_1), template errors out to 'MultiIndex' object is not callable.

Comment: If I use Jupyter Notebook and do : df1 = pd.pivot_table(df, index='week', columns=['car_name', 'fruit_name'], values='price', fill_value="")
df1.style.applymap(color_red); it works without having to to subset, but not in my webpage.